# After renaming ASP.NET_SessionId - it still appears in Request Headers - how to resolve?

Tags: iis, cookies, asp.net-session

We are trying to remove references in the headers to ASP.Net

In our .Net MVC project, the web config contains:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider" cookieName="newCookie">
```

In the host headers when viewing through the web server (IIS) I see:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=....
newCookie=.....
```

However when I test locally, I don't see the ASP.NET_SessionId  reference.

I also renamed the forms authentication cookie name to something else.

What am I missing?

Comment: Clear your cookies and watch the responses as you hit the web server; you may be hitting another ASP.NET application and being redirected to the one with the updated config.